# Expressjs - stream cassandra result set to client

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra, stream

I have to stream the json resultset stream returned by cassandra to the browser. I got it working using express-stream but that involved stringifying the each row and and passing it to res.pipe()

I am wondering why following didn't work:

```
app.get('/api/v1/streamevents', function (req, res) {
   let cstream = client.stream(selectQuery, ['339aa84a-4bba-411f-a4fb-38167a987cd2'],options)
   cstream.pipe(res)

})
```

I get following error:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:458:11)
    at ResultStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ResultStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at ResultStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:381:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cassandra-cql#clientstreamquery-params-consistency-callback) for the `stream` method of Cassandra driver:

> Returns a Readable Streams2 object in objectMode

At the same time, underlying `ServerResponse.write` only accepts either `String` or `Buffer` as a data chunk when sending to the client, not `Object`.

That's why it works when each row is stringified.

You would have to use a `Transform` stream in the middle to convert the selected cell values to string.